# How to browse link inside on an android app without using browser

Tags: android, cordova

Recently I created an online newspaper android app using phonegap. That means the app is made of html/css. I have added online newspaper links on it, so when someone clicks on the links, they will be redirected to their browser and can browse the online newspaper. But I don't want this - I would like when people click on the link, for them to be able to browse the online newspaper inside the application, so they wouldn't need a browser to view the link. But I don't know how to create something like that. Remember, this is created using phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the InAppBrowser plugin: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

*According to the above link:*

From the command line:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

Add in `app/res/xml/config.xml`:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

Then you can open any URL using

```
var url = "<some URL>";
var ref = window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Or, you can try using an iframe instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you tell me how to insert this on eclips since i am making it on an eclips

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you tell me how to insert this on eclips since i am making it on an eclips

Comment: @user3425602 I added instructions above. I don't think it's any different in Eclipse than any other IDE.

Comment: I don't want something like that.In this article it is created only for 1 link..think when i have created a newspaper app which have every country listed. there are so many links.That means i have make a command that can be use for browse any of the link they click not the specific one link

Comment: See my edit. You can set `url` to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap has a plugin called ChildBrowser. You can use that plugin to build a browser inside your app itself and open everything inside it.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser/blob/f9e9c7d9266dc229efa3ad495da79e7a60e4e2e3/README.md

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you tell me how to insert this on eclips since i am making it on an eclips

Comment: I don't want something like that.In this article it is created only for 1 link..think when i have created a newspaper app which have every country listed. there are so many links.That means i have make a command that can be use for browse any of the link they click not the specific one link